# ϵ-greedy policy with decreasing rate of exploration

Tags: machine-learning, greedy, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

I want to implement ϵ-greedy policy action-selection policy in Q-learning. Here many people have used, following equation for decreasing rate of exploration,

ɛ = e^(-En)

n = the age of the agent

E = exploitation parameter

But I am not clear what does this "n" means? is that number of visits to a particular state-action pair OR is that the number of iterations?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several valid answers for your question. From the theoretical point of view, in order to achieve convergence, Q-learning requires that all the state-action pairs are (asymptotically) visited infinitely often.

The previous condition can be achieved in many ways. In my opinion, it's more common to interpret `n` simply as the number of time steps, i.e., how many interactions the agent has performed with the environment [e.g., [Busoniu, 2010, Chapter 2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1439821089)].

However, in some cases the rate of exploration can be different for each state, and therefore `n`  is the number of times the agent has visited state `s` [e.g., [Powell, 2011, chapter 12](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/047060445X)].

Both interpreations are equally valid and ensure (together other conditions) the asymptotic convergence of Q-learning. When is better to use some approach or another depends on your particular problem, similar to what exact value of `E` you should use.